# Delete a record from an array VB.NET

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to delete a record from an array in `VB.Net` but I can never get it to delete the correct one

In my code, `intPosition` is the position where the desired record I want to delete is.  `Customers` is the name of the 3D array and `NumberOfCustomers` can be treated as the size of the array.

```
  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        NumberOfCustomers -= 1
        For i = intPosition + 1 To NumberOfCustomers
            Customers(i - 1) = Customers(i)
        Next
        NumberOfCustomers -= 1
        ReDim Preserve Customers(NumberOfCustomers)
        Call SaveCustomer()
    End If
```

Please could someone amend or find similar code for this in `VB.NET`.

Thanks

Comment: You are torturing the array.  Use a `List(Of T)` or something better suited to the types of things you are trying to do.

Comment: rather than an array, if it was a `List(Of Customer)` (which will take all of 15 mins to learn about)  `Customers.RemoveAt(indexToRemove)` is all you need

Comment: Also, are you sure this is VB.NET?  There is no such enum `MessageBoxButtons`.  It should be `MsgBoxStyle`.

Comment: Maybe they created their own message box?

Comment: @roryap There's a [`MessageBoxButtons`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum in the `System.Windows` namespace, although it should be used with the `MessageBox` class and not with the `MsgBox` VB function.

Comment: @DStanley what's it used for?  When I use `MsgBox`, it's looking for `MsgBoxStyle`.

Comment: @roryap It's used by the `MessageBox` class.  The `MessageBoxClass breaks the buttons, defaults, and icons into separate enums.

Answer (score 4):

I would propose you do without the array as it's extremely inefficient for operations like this.  Instead, you should use one of the built-in classes like [`List(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is much better suited for how you're trying to use it.

```
Dim customers = New List(Of Customer)

'populate your list however you do it.

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    customers.RemoveAt(position)
End If
```